# Defining metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

As far as I am told, a metric space is a set with distances defined between every two members of my set. So, if I have two sequences ${\left\{a_i\right\}_1}^n$ and ${\left\{b_i\right\}_1}^n$ and I define my set as a space of double points $\mathrm{S}:=\left\{(a_i,b_j)\right\}$ and define my distance $d$ between two set members$(a_i,b_j),(a_k,b_l)$ as $d=\left|a_i+a_k+b_j+b_l\right|$, then would I have a metric space? or is there a conservative definition of distance that I would need to adhere to?

Comment: It kind of looks like you read the first sentence of the wiki, and then didn't bother to [scroll down to the answer to your question](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Definition). Apologies if I'm mistaken. Anyway, try that.

Answer (score 4):

The wikipedia page for [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) lists the axioms that a metric would need to have.  In particular, $d: X\times X \to \mathbb{R}$ must satisfy:

- $d(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x=y$
- Symmetry: $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$
- Non-negativity: $d(x,y)\geq 0$
- Triangle Inequality: $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$

Your definition does not define a metric because the distance between $(a_i,b_j)$ and itself need not be zero unless $a_i=-b_j$.  Moreover, the distance between two such tuples being zero does not imply that the two pairs are equal (for example, your distance between $(0,1)$ and $(-1,0)$ is zero, but those certainly aren't equal).

It is, however, non-negative, symmetric, and satisfies the triangle inequality.  Even if you chose your tuples to always be of the form $(a,-a)$ so that $d(x,x)=0$, you still wouldn't get a metric space (unless you only had a single point) because in fact $d(x,y)=0$ for all $x,y$.